# A-Frame. Zoom on wheel scroll

Tags: aframe

I've come through the official docs but wasn't able to locate information about how possibility of zooming in/out `panorama` images, is it supported in the A-Frame or maybe there is a workaround to read about implementing some of `three.js` on top of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either:

1. Scale an `<a-sphere>` up or down when detecting the mouse wheel event
2. zoom in or out the camera, like documented [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/camera.html)

[This article](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/) might be helpful, as it covers using the mousewheel event on multiple browsers.

I think scaling may screw up Your setup, or be a resource waste, so I'd go with 2.

Answer (score 6):

This might be a cleaner way in 2018.
I limited the zoom of the Aframe camera 1-5 so it doesn't get too messy.I just tested this and its working greatly.Hope it helps others.

```
window.addEventListener("mousewheel", event => {
    const delta = Math.sign(event.wheelDelta);
    //getting the mouse wheel change (120 or -120 and normalizing it to 1 or -1)
    var mycam=document.getElementById('cam').getAttribute('camera');
    var finalZoom=document.getElementById('cam').getAttribute('camera').zoom+delta;
    //limiting the zoom so it doesnt zoom too much in or out
    if(finalZoom<1)
      finalZoom=1;
    if(finalZoom>5)
      finalZoom=5;  

    mycam.zoom=finalZoom;
    //setting the camera element
    document.getElementById('cam').setAttribute('camera',mycam);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Sandy's answer helped me. I want to contribute an answer which shows the full code and enables smoother zooming (increments of 0.1):

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
    // small increments for smoother zooming
    const delta = event.wheelDelta / 120 / 10;
    var mycam = document.getElementById("cam").getAttribute("camera");
    var finalZoom =
      document.getElementById("cam").getAttribute("camera").zoom + delta;

    // limiting the zoom
    if (finalZoom < 0.5) finalZoom = 0.5;
    if (finalZoom > 2) finalZoom = 2;
    mycam.zoom = finalZoom;

    document.getElementById("cam").setAttribute("camera", mycam);
  });
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity
    id="cam"
    camera="zoom: 1"
    look-controls="reverseMouseDrag: true"
  ></a-entity>
  <!-- my pano image stuff -->
  <a-assets>
    <img id="skyTexture" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  </a-assets>
  <a-sky src="#skyTexture"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I put together to do it. Check the initial vrZoom variable.

For me, what I struggled the most, was to understand the way you set a parameter that's inside a component. You have to call it like this: `element.setAttribute('componentName', 'parameterName', 'value')` and in my case `cam.setAttribute('camera', 'zoom', vrZoom)`

Here's my script all together. It would be possible to create a component with this, such as look-controls.

```
var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";

if (document.attachEvent)
  document.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, function(e){scroller(e)});
else if (document.addEventListener)
  document.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, function(e){scroller(e)},false);

var vrZoom = 4; // My initial zoom after animation
var cam = document.querySelector('#mainCam');

function scroller(evt)
{
  //Guess the delta.
  var delta = 0;
  if (!evt) evt = window.event;
  if (evt.wheelDelta) {
    delta = evt.wheelDelta/120;
  } else if (evt.detail) {
    delta = -evt.detail/3;
  }
  if (evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
  evt.returnValue = false;

  //Actual Zooming.
  vrZoom += delta * 0.1
  vrZoom = Math.min(Math.max(vrZoom, 1), 8); // clamp between 1 and 8
  cam.setAttribute('camera', 'zoom', vrZoom)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled quite a bit with getting this to work for an embedded a-frame, especially because the scene would become skewed upon dynamically adjusting the camera's zoom setting. This is a bug with a-frame. Here are the two ways I found to reset the scene upon setting the zoom level.

```
AFRAME.scenes[0].resize();
```

Or ...

```
let scene = document.querySelector('a-scene');
scene.camera.aspect = scene.clientWidth / scene.clientHeight;
scene.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```