# Zoom in and out in aframe sky element

Tags: aframe

I made an simple 360 image viewer. But I want to make zoom in and zoom out effect while whelling mouse.

Do you have a sample code or example for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A-Frame. Zoom on wheel scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459356/a-frame-zoom-on-wheel-scroll)

Comment: Here is my code;

<a-scene>
<a-sky src="360image.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0">
<a-animation attribute="rotation" fill="forwards" easing="linear" dur="150000" from="0 0 0" to="0 360 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>  
</a-sky>
<a-entity zoom="2"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
Where shoul I put "" code into my script? Can you give an example please, if possible?

Thank you